# Check if strings in db start with a word from an array

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given this db:

```
symbol name

xyz    xyz machines
bly    bolins communications
```

Where symbols are unique, names are not, 5000 rows.
I then have an array of words:

```
array = ["xjf","bly","xxx","colins"]
```

I need to find all rows where :

1. One of the words in array are `exactly` equal to a `symbol` field.
2. **OR** - if the `name` column *start with* one of these words.

I have done   :

```
    SELECT symbol,name
    FROM index_v1
    WHERE symbol IN ('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz')
```

I also wonder **how to index this to make it fast.**

Answer (score 0):

Done with `ilike` and `any` :

```
WHERE symbol IN ('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz') OR name ILIKE any (array['xxx%%', 'yyy%%', 'zzz%%'])
```